# How can I change the CSS of the files that get generated with 'grails doc' in Grails

Tags: grails, documentation, textile

When I use `grails doc`, the tables I'm using in the markdown language have no padding, and I'd like to add some for readability. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks tim_yates. This is a more concise question. I'm still learning the ins and outs of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add custom css via [configuration](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#docengine).

> grails.doc.css - The location of a directory containing custom CSS files (type java.io.File)

Example:

```
grails.doc.css = new File("src/docs/css")
```